# D3js zoom does not work

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, zooming, pan

I can not make zoom work. Tried everything.
My goal:

- zoom on mouse scroll
- drag the tree by a mouse

The code is here:

```
svg = d3.select("#tree-container")
        .append("svg").attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .call(zm = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 3]).on("zoom", redraw))
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 350 + "," + 20 + ")");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pnTXd/2/)

P.S. sorry for spaggeti code

Comment: If possible, please reformat your code in jsfiddle, I got severe pain in my eyes after looking at your code for 20 sec (seriously)... :)

Comment: I've formatted my code. http://jsfiddle.net/pnTXd/2/

Comment: That's much much better, thank you!

Comment: Everything to resolve the question :)

Comment: Works fine if you declare `redraw` as a function -- http://jsfiddle.net/pnTXd/3/

Comment: Interesting thing, coffeescript converts this function as variable-function. And i could not implement this function on coffescript (without declaration of a class). Anyway it's right answer, submit it :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the declaration of your `redraw` function that causes the problem -- if you declare it as a function, it works fine:

```
function redraw() {
  // etc
}
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pnTXd/3/).